# Magento 2.0 override admin css (style.css)

Tags: magento2

I am working in magento 2.0 and want to make changes in admin login panel.
please suggest me how to override admin css files or how to add new css file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a custom module and define css in desired xml or if you want to add in all pages create **default.xml**

1) add a module Ex. Emizentech/NewAdmin

2) create a new file **view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml** in the module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
     <css src="css/emizentech.css"/>
   </head>
</page>
```

3) Add .css file in web folder as below path:

```
view/adminhtml/web/css/emizentech.css
```

after this you need to clear cache and deploy static content

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way to create child theme so when you update magento your change not remove.

You can create child theme as like created for frontend theme.

Backend this are `vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend`.

You can get reference for create child theme from `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma`, because that this is child theme of `Magento/blank`, you can check that from file `vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/theme.xml`.

For more about create theme you can get reference form: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to exactly the same thing for quite a while. Turns out that you don't need to create a module at all. Just like how you can override files by overriding them in your frontend theme (app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme), you can do the same thing for the backend (app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/theme).