# Correct way of app/design and app/code usage Magento 2 Adminhtml

Tags: php, module, magento2

I wish to understand two things:

1. Extend the Magento 2 Admin CSS ( or correct way for doing less?) to copy CSS/less from original back-end
2. Override in back-end for example : Sales > Orders > the called file vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/pageactions.phtml

I have followed
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html
&
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_apply.html

Checked different stackoverflow posts like

[Magento 2.0 override admin css (style.css)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458644/magento-2-0-override-admin-css-style-css)

But I'm at an loss at the moment understanding this correctly.

I would wish to override the CSS for the magento login for example. When do I use the app/code, and when do I use app/design and for what reasons? In this example **I'm trying both and I'm not sure where to place what where for what reason. Some posts refer to overriding through app/code, but my app/design css change works too, which is correct?**

I was succesful in creating a custom page for the backend, through this module I also activate the custom adminhtml template through di.xml, and show my own logo on the admin login so that works, I also have custom CSS. I won't bother you with the parts that are working so I'll leave the Index.php, menu.xml, routes.xml, exampleadminnewpage_helloworld_index and files in templates out of this because that works fine.

app/code file structure

```
        app/code/Vendor   
        └── ExampleAdminNewPage
            ├── composer.json
            ├── Controller
            │   └── Adminhtml
            │       └── HelloWorld
            │           └── Index.php
            ├── etc
            │   ├── adminhtml
            │   │   ├── menu.xml
            │   │   └── routes.xml
            │   ├── di.xml
            │   └── module.xml
            ├── registration.php
            └── view
                └── adminhtml
                    ├── layout
                    │   └── exampleadminnewpage_helloworld_index.xml
                    └── templates
                        ├── helloworld.phtml
                        ├── intro.css
                        └── js.phtml
```

app/code/Vendor/ExampleAdminNewPage/etc/di.xml

```
        <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
            <type name="Magento\Theme\Model\View\Design">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="themes" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="adminhtml" xsi:type="string">Vendor/Test_Admin</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </type>
        </config>
```

app/code/Vendor/ExampleAdminNewPage/registration.php

```
    <?php
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
        \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Vendor_ExampleAdminNewPage',
        __DIR__
    );
```

app/code/Vendor/ExampleAdminNewPage/etc/module.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
            <module name="Vendor_ExampleAdminNewPage" setup_version="1.0.0">
                <sequence>
                    <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
                </sequence>
            </module>
        </config>
```

app/design file structure

```
     app/design/adminhtml/Vendor
        └── Test_Admin
            ├── Magento_Sales
            │   └── templates
            │       ├── items
            │       │   └── column
            │       │       └── name.phtml
            │       └── pageactions.phtml
            ├── registration.php
            ├── theme.xml
            └── web
                ├── css
                │   └── styles.css
                ├── images
                │   └── magento-logo.svg > This is my own logo and this shows at the admin login!
                └── js
                    └── requirejs-config.js
```

**The following echo doesn't work, I had expected that if I went to sales>orders, I'd see this echo?**    app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/Test_Admin/Magento_Sales/templates/items/column/name.phtml

```
    <?php echo 'test'; ?>
```

**Same goes for this echo, I expected to see the echo at Sales>Orders**
app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/Test_Admin/Magento_Sales/templates/pageactions.phtml

```
    <?php echo 'testpageaction'; ?>
```

**The CSS works, but am I supposed to do it through this way? And where can I find the original back-end css/less?**
app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/Test_Admin/web/css/styles.css

```
    span {
        background-color: red !important;
    }
```

I also don't know how to get JS working, currently I have.
app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/Test_Admin/web/js/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            customAdmin: 'Vendor_Test_Admin/js/customAdmin'
        }
    },
    deps: ["jquery"]
};
```

app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/Test_Admin/registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'adminhtml/Vendor/Test_admin', // Example: 'adminhtml/Magento/backend'
    __DIR__
);
```

public_html/app/design/adminhtml/Vendor/Test_Admin/theme.xml

```
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Test_Admin Theme</title> <!-- your theme's name -->
    <parent>Magento/backend</parent> <!-- the parent theme. Example: Magento/backend -->
</theme>
```

I hope my question is clear, It's a bit unclear for me and that's why maybe I can't word it correctly but I hope what I currently have is enough.